# Add another propertymapping? (AutoMapper)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Can you

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>() 
        .ForMember(x => x.IsFoo, x => x.Ignore());
```

and then later on add another mapping of the sort

```
  .ForMember(x => x.IsBar, x => x.Ignore());
```

or even change the old one

```
  .ForMember(x => x.IsFor, x => x.MapFrom(z => z.IsBar));
```

? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. Mappings in AutoMapper are defined only once per application domain preferably in your application initialization method. Quote from the [documentation](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Documentation):

> If you're using the static Mapper
>   method, configuration only needs to
>   happen once per AppDomain. That means
>   the best place to put the
>   configuration code is in application
>   startup, such as the Global.asax file
>   for ASP.NET applications. Typically,
>   the configuration bootstrapper class
>   is in its own class, and this
>   bootstrapper class is called from the
>   startup method.

Answer (score 1):

try calling `Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()` each time before mappping